# Collecting Like, Share, comments from facebook using facebook api

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, urllib

I am trying to scrape a public facebook page using facebook api, but every time i sent request it return

> HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

I am putting correct access token, which is app id + "|" + app_secret. But still return Bad request. For safety reason I hide my **app id** and **app secret code**.

```
import facebook
import urllib3
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import json
import datetime
import csv
import time

app_id = 'facebook_app_id'
app_secret = 'facebook_app_secret' 

access_token = app_id + "|" + app_secret

fb_page = "manchesterunited"



base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2"
node = "/" + fb_page
parameters = "/? 

fields=message,link,created_time,type,name,id,likes.limit(1).summary(true),comments.limit(1).summary(true),shares&limit=%s&access_token=%s" % (100, access_token)
 url = base + node + parameters

def request_until_succeed(url):
    req = Request(url)
    success = False
    while success is False:
        try:
            response = urlopen(req)
            if response.getcode() == 200:
                success = True
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            time.sleep(5)

            print("Error for URL %s: %s" % (url, datetime.datetime.now()))

   return response.read()
 test_status = json.loads(request_until_succeed(url))["data"][0]
 print (json.dumps(test_status, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

With a simple App Access Token and a Public Page you do not own, you first need to get approved for Page Public Content Access: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

Alternatively, for testing, you can use a Page Token of a Page you own.

More information about Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Can you please kindly tell me how can i approve my app. Thanks in advance

Comment: in your app settings, just go to "app review", there you can add permissions and functionality to send it in. there´s a lot of information in there, just read all of it. the process is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access public pages any more without getting your app reviewed for this upfront.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS:

> **Page Public Content Access**
>   Allows read-only access to public data on Pages for which you lack the manage_page login permission. Readable data includes business metadata, public comments, posts, and reviews.